# Why does my function only insert 240 entries into SQLite when the array contains over 3000 elements?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to insert all elements from an NSArray (tpInfo) and insert them into an SQLite Database. But only the first 15 rows are being populated, which is 240 entries.  tpInfo contains over 3000 elements.  I've been stuck here for a while, and would appreciate a point in the right direction.

I have tried changing my for loop to increment 'i' by 1, that enters more data, but it's inserted into the incorrect columns/rows and throws an NSRangeException.

'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 2304 beyond bounds [0 .. 2303]'

```
-(void) insertTP: (NSMutableArray * ) tpInfo {

NSString * databasePath = [self dataPath: @ "eldb.sqlite3"];
sqlite3 * database;
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], & database) != SQLITE_OK) {
  NSLog(@ "Could not open database");
  return;
} else {
  NSLog(@ "Inserting TimeProfile Data");
}

//for each element in the array, save the array index
sqlite3_stmt * statement;
NSString * SQLInsert = @ "INSERT INTO TIME_PROFILES (TIMEZONE_IID, 
TIMEZONE_ID, SERIAL, FROM_TIME, TO_TIME ,MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, 
THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, HOLIDAY, SPECIAL_DAY_ONE, 
SPECIAL_DAY_TWO, TIMEZONE_ITEM_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [SQLInsert UTF8String], -1, & statement, 
nil) == SQLITE_OK) {

  NSLog(@ "pinfo %@", tpInfo);

  for (int i = 0; i < [tpInfo count]; i += 16) {

  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [tpInfo[i] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [tpInfo[i + 1] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [tpInfo[i + 2] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [tpInfo[i + 3] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [tpInfo[i + 4] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [tpInfo[i + 5] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [tpInfo[i + 6] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 8, [tpInfo[i + 7] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 9, [tpInfo[i + 8] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 10, [tpInfo[i + 9] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 11, [tpInfo[i + 10] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 12, [tpInfo[i + 11] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 13, [tpInfo[i + 12] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 14, [tpInfo[i + 13] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 15, [tpInfo[i + 14] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 16, [tpInfo[i + 15] UTF8String], -1, NULL);

  if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    NSLog(@"Database returned error %d: %s", sqlite3_errcode(database), sqlite3_errmsg(database));
  }
  sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
} else {
  NSLog(@ "Can't prepare: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
 sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: "throws an exception" What exception?

Comment: @Larme, I have updated my question..

Comment: You're ignoring the error returned by `sqlite3_step`. Investigate the error it returns and it should tell you what's going on. I suspect you have bad data in your array.

Comment: @RobNapier, Yes, but even before the error, data is inserted into incorrect rows/columns.

Comment: That was because you switched to `i += 1`, correct? You can't do that with this code. Your database appears to have 16 columns, and your array appears to be laid out in a matrix format (which is generally not a good way to store record data, but it's what this code appears to expect). If you change the stride to 1, you're going to insert row 1, column 2 data into row 2, column 1.

Comment: @RobNapier, yes pretty much (i++).  Yes my database table has 16 columns.  My array is an NSMutableArray, unsure of format.      That kind of makes sense..

Comment: According to this code, the array is in the format `r1c1, r1c2, r1c3,...r1c16, r2c1, r2c2` where "r1c1" is "row 1, column 1". That's what I meant by "matrix format." Typically this kind of thing would be laid out as an array of some model object, where that model object has 16 properties. But the key point here is to check your error message. It will probably tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @RobNapier I added in some NSLog and the error returned:  UNIQUE constraint failed: TIME_PROFILES.TIMEZONE_ID.

Comment: You are trying to run your loop `[tpInfo count]` times but, since you're using up 16 members of the array on each loop, the number of loops should be `[tpInfo count] / 16`.

Comment: @flatwhite I would say you've found your problem. The TIMEZONE_ID is marked UNIQUE, but you're inserting multiple rows with the same time TIMEZONE_ID. I suspect your database schema is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way this is coded, your tpInfo array has 16 columns of data in the first 16 elements (0-15) from TIMEZONE_IID to TIMEZONE_ITEM_ID for the first row, then the second 16 elements (16-31) for the second row.  If so, this is a strange way to populate your tpInfo array.  That should be an array of TimeProfile objects that have 16 attributes, and then you would only increment the for loop by += 1.

This way, what happens if [tpInfo count] is not perfectly divisible by 16?  You're going to get index out of bounds error, which may be what is failing.

Your code should probably look more like this (assuming you have a TimeProfile class object):

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [SQLInsert UTF8String], -1, & statement, 
nil) == SQLITE_OK) {

for (int i = 0; i < [tpInfo count]; i += 1) {
    TimeProfile *profile = tpInfo[I];
     NSLog(@ "pinfo %@", profile);

  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [profile.TIMEZONE_IID UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [profile.TIMEZONE_ID UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [profile.SERIAL UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [profile.FROM_TIME UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [profile.TO_TIME UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [profile.MONDAY UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [profile.TUESDAY UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 8, [profile.WEDNESDAY UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 9, [profile.THURSDAY UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 10, [profile.FRIDAY UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 11, [profile.SATURDAY UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 12, [profile.SUNDAY UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 13, [profile.HOLIDAY UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 14, [profile.SPECIAL_DAY_ONE UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 15, [profile.SPECIAL_DAY_TWO UTF8String], -1, NULL);
  sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 16, [profile.SPECIAL_DAY_THREE UTF8String], -1, NULL);

  if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    NSLog(@"Database returned error %d: %s", sqlite3_errcode(database), sqlite3_errmsg(database));
  }

  sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
} else {
  NSLog(@ "Can't prepare: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
 sqlite3_close(database);
}
```